# Spring 3 MVC + Hibernate 3.5.x : Autowiring and Dependency Injection of SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I am new to Spring framework; need some clarifications on how the `SessionFactory` object Dependency injection is working in below code.

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.employee" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:employee.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

**EmployeeDAOImpl.java**

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void addEmployee(EmployeeForm employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
}
}
```

How is the sessionFactory getting initialized with a SessionFactory object here?

**What I understand**

In the `sprng-servlet.xml` file, the DI of `sessionFactory` is happening in the below code:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Now, if I open the source code for the class `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager`, then I can see the below section:

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public HibernateTransactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    afterPropertiesSet();
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return this.sessionFactory;
}
```

which means the `sessionFactory` class variable of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` has been initializd.

**Now my Query:**

In my code posted above, how is the `sessionFactory` of class `EmployeeDAOImpl.java` getting initialized? I can't find any relation between the `sessionFactory` of class `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager` (where DI is happening) and the `sessionFactory` of class `EmployeeDAOImpl.java` (which I wrote). Then how is it working?

Please explain - totally confused !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:employee.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You have defined the session factory bean in you context file. During the application bootstrap, the spring context is loaded and this session factory bean is initialized by spring as a singleton instance.

```
<context:annotation-config /> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.employee" />

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

And since you have enabled the annotation-config and component-scan and declared @Autowired in your DAOImp, this is the reason Spring knows the place to inject the session factory bean properly.

This configuration is enabled the transaction manager annotation.
Example:

```
@Transactional
public void addEmployee(EmployeeForm employee){...}
```

Here is the suggestion.

Transactional annotation is better to be placed in service layer instead of DAO layer. You need to make sure the annotation is placed on the concrete class unless you use the interface-proxy in your component-scan.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

This piece of configuration is set the transaction manager bean which lets transaction manager knows which session factory it needs to manage with.

Therefore the configuration of bean

id="transactionManager" sets the transaction manager with the proper hibernate session factory.

tx:annotation-driven configuration enables the annotation-based transaction manager in code level.

Hope the explanation is helpful for you. :)

Comment: If I am having multiple database, then I need multiple sessionFactory. How to handle this scenario? In that case there will be multiple sessionFactories entries right? Can you please explain?

Comment: You can have multiple session factories with different data sources. Then you need to have multiple transaction managers. In code level, you can define transaction managers as @Transactional("first"), @Transactional("second"), name "first" and "second" map to the transaction manager configurations in you context file such as <bean id="transactionManager1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    ...<qualifier value="first"/>
</bean>

Comment: And please make sure the spring version you use is 3.x above. :)

Comment: One more basic question: can you please explain this line: `<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">`? If I replace this line with this : `<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="com.employee.EmployeeServiceImpl">` then I am telling to inject the `sessionFactory` of the context in the `sessionFactory` class variable of `EmployeeServiceImpl` class - right? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: No, you should not replace this line with your custom class, org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean is a hibernate session factory class. It has the functions to create the sessions. Since you use hibernate, then this is the factory class which has ability to create the sessions for you. Service class is a different level, since you have your DAOs, then you should inject your DAOs into your Service class.

Comment: In my code I cant find any place where I am telling the framework to inject the sessionFactory of context into sessionFactory of DAOImpl class. Then how is the framework come to know where exactly to inject? What if I have multiple DOImpl class with same sessionFactory? In that case all will be initialized with the same object right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51473/discussion-between-user182944-and-corec)

Comment: Yes, each of your DAO needs to have a session factory to get the current session which enables the query by Criteria or HQL. Since you use spring and hibernate 3, then spring provides a hibernateTemplate class you can use and you only need to pass the session factory to it once.